# Getting duplicate lines on left outer join which includes count(distinct ...)

Tags: google-bigquery

The following query returns duplicate lines on big query.
Was expecting to get one line with value "1":

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT 1 AS line
FROM [...]
) AS a
left outer JOIN EACH (
SELECT 1 AS line
FROM [...] 
) AS b
ON a.line = b.line
```

Query Results 11:36am, 13 May 2015

Row a_line  b_line
1   1   1
2   1   1
3   1   1
4   1   1
5   1   1
First< Prev Rows 1-5 of 1225 Next >Last

Comment: Could you elaborate on the problem?

Comment: was expecting to get just 1 line with value 1.

Comment: If I remove the "from" clauses from both queries I get the correct results: Row a_line b_line  
1 1 1

Comment: Are you using data structure which is repeated? You might see the auto flatten thing that the UI does.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. It happens regardless of which tables I choose in each query, the same ones or different ones.

Comment: there is no group by in the query

Comment: No need here, I'm only selecting one value. But you can add it, it won't make any difference.

Answer (score 2):

That's the correct behavior. For each row in table a, you are getting a '1'. For each row in table b, you are getting another '1'. Joining them on that key will give you #rows(a)*#rows(b) '1 1's. You are effectively doing a CROSS JOIN between 2 tables.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
  SELECT 1 as x FROM [fh-bigquery:geocode.numbers_255]
)
256


SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
  SELECT 1 as x FROM [fh-bigquery:geocode.numbers_255] a   
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 1 as x FROM [fh-bigquery:geocode.numbers_255]) b
)
65536
```

If you only want 1 '1':

```
SELECT 1 as line
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a BQ bug due to old version in Google. If you encounter this ask BQ support to update your version.
Thanks for the responses :)